# My Mac crashes when it runs out of RAM

Tags: macos, memory, crash

I have a perplexing problem with my Macbook Pro (16GB RAM, OS X 10.8.4). If I use up all my main memory, the computer crashes. The screen freezes on whatever window it was on (not a kernel panic), and is totally unresponsive.

I have also noticed that the "wired" memory usage in Activity Monitor seems to get very high - most of my RAM usage is "wired". And even upon boot, there is a kernel_task process that uses 1.5GB + of memory which seems somewhat high. These points may or may not be relevant.

I know I have needed virtual memory in the past and had no problems, so I have no idea what is wrong. It seems as if the computer just flat-out refuses to use virtual memory - that would certainly explain the crash. In fact, my /private/var/vm/ folder does not even exist.

Comment: if you have a hard drive (as opposed to a solid state drive) any virtual memory provided by the disk will be orders of magnitude slower than RAM -- additionally your computer freezes (perfectly normal), not crashes, when you run out of RAM, given what you say

Comment: I have an SSD. I think you misunderstand my problem. I'm not experiencing slow-down, the machine is 100% unresponsive, and I can leave it like that for half an hour or more and it still won't respond. This is not normal.

Comment: If you have a SSD you should not have a drastic degradation of performance when processes move to the SSD from RAM -- is the hardware ok?

Comment: try resetting your SDC

Comment: Problem solved! See edit of original post. user1256923, the problem was that my system simply _refused_ to use the SSD as virtual memory. "Totally unresponsive" and "crash" are not synonymous with "slow" ;).

Comment: Are the 16 Gig original Apple or did you overstuffed it? What year is your MBP?

Comment: It's great that you've found the issue, but in order to make this question useful to other visitors to the site, please add an Answer to the question and accept that answer, instead of editing the answer *into* the question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Moriarty - the all in one "answer at the top" and question as an edit isn't helpful to the site. Please put your answer in the answer section so that your work can be credited to you...

Comment: Apologies, I had to wait until the site would let me answer my own question. Though it won't let me accept my own answer till tomorrow - seems odd to me. Done now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the simple solution sometimes is the proper one after all! It seems /private/var/vm/ should always exist (even if it is empty, ie on restart), so however it got deleted the answer was to just `sudo mkdir /private/var/vm/`. Seemingly non-robust coding on Apple's part, but at least it's fixed. Never mind!